# Loan Calculator Equation error C#

Tags: c#, date, math, time, calculator

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace IndividualAssignmentLoan {

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        jmToday.Caption = Format(Now, "DDDD, D/MMMM/YYYY")
    }

    protected void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double amount = double.Parse(jmLoanAmount.Text);
        double downPay = double.Parse(jmDownPayment.Text);
        double interest = double.Parse(jmInterestRate.Text);
        int period = int.Parse(jmLoanPeriod.Text);

        Double monthlyPay;
        Double loanCost;

        monthlyPay = ((amount * interest) / 1) - (Math.Pow(1/(1 + interest), period));
        loanCost = monthlyPay * (period * 12);

        jmMonthlyPayment.Text = monthlyPay.ToString();
        jmTotalLoanCost.Text = loanCost.ToString();
    }
}
}
```

Hi, I've written to the point where I do not understand where I am going wrong with my loan calculator. I've input my formula to get the loan amount as...

```
monthlyPay = ((amount * interest) / 1) - (Math.Pow(1/(1 + interest), period));
```

I've tried other ways of getting the correct amount, but nothing seems to give me the monthly amount I need. Can someone help me with the formula. Oh an my clock I have on top lol...

```
jmToday.Caption = Format(Now, "DDDD, D/MMMM/YYYY")
```

Comment: What does `/ 1` do?

Comment: I don't have the answer yet but one issue i see is you are dividing by 1 here `(amount * interest) / 1`

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `amount`, `interest`, `period`? It would be awesome if you could produce a [mcve] (preferably in a console app) which includes sample inputs and outputs that you are expecting for those sample inputs.

Comment: Amount is totalAmount, interest is the interest % entered, period is the number of years. All of these are user input.

Comment: The formula given by my professor was : L*R/1-(1/1+r)^n. In this L is amount, R is interest, and n is period

Comment: Please show your sample input data, expected output, and actual output. Describe **what is wrong** rather than just saying, *"nothing seems to give me the monthly amount I need"*

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hate it when teachers teach students to use double for money-related operations. Always use decimal, kids! 128-bit non-floating point goodness (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)

Anyway, I think I deciphered what your teacher intended with the formula (your comment was ambiguous to say the least). I think you want:

```
double actualAmountToPay = amount - downPay;
double monthlyPay = actualAmountToPay * interest / (1 - 1 / Math.Pow((1 + interest), period));
double totalCost = monthlyPay * (period * 12);
```

Comment: Apologize about that

Comment: No worries, it was just confusing to interpret, since a/ 1 == 1 as others mentioned.

Comment: Did you get to try this formula?

Answer (score 0):

Leave btnClick handling parsing and move monthly payment calculation to a separate method:

```
double CalculateMonthlyPayment(double amount, double downPayment, int termInYears, double interestRate)
{
    int paymentsCount = MonthsPerYear * termInYears;
    double principal = amount - downPayment;

    if (interestRate == 0)
    {
        return principal / paymentsCount;
    }

    double monthlyRate = interestRate / MonthsPerYear;
    double coefficient = Math.Pow(1 + monthlyRate, paymentsCount);
    double monthlyPayment = principal * (monthlyRate * coefficient) / (coefficient - 1);

    return monthlyPayment;
}
```

`MonthsPerYear` is a constant with an obvious value.

`TotalPayment` will be `paymentsCount * MonthlyPayment`

Keep in mind that you need to handle exception cases: `amount <= 0`, `downPayment < 0`, `amount <= downPayment`, `termInMonths < 1`. Also decide if you allow negative interest rate.